Perfect cross in a \fbox square
I'm trying to put a perfect cross (just like $\boxtimes$) in the following square \fbox{\texttt{A}}. Any hint? Find below my code:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\texttt{A}}  \textcolor{blue}{$\boxtimes$}

\end{document}


Would you be willing to scale up \boxtimes? Or does the symbol have to be based on \fbox?

I prefer the second option because \texttt{A} must be inside the box... but if no other option is available, then yes, scaling \boxtimes shall be a solution (and I think I can handle it).

A TikZ-based solution may be called for...

Ok, and how can that be achieved?

Hopefully, a TikZ specialist will step up soon and take the challenge. :-)

Can you please add sone screenshots to your question? The box-limits seem a bit vague to me. Did you inspect other fonts, e.g. from the a4…pdf ?

The box-limits are exactly the ones of \fbox{\texttt{A}}; I don't know precisely (i.e., numerically) the values. Other fonts, how’s that? The font I'm using is the standard one. Looking at \boxtimes, the cross is perfectly fitted in the square; it's possible to know how thus command was created? If so, then a solution would be reproduce it for \fbox{\texttt{A}}...

Wrong recall abt the filname: Scan here: https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

With tikz
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mybox}{ O{blue} m }{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        mycolor/.style={#1}
        ]
        \node[mycolor](X){\texttt{#2}};
        \draw[mycolor]  (X.north west) rectangle (X.south east)
                        (X.north west)--(X.south east)
                        (X.south west)--(X.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    % or
%     \NewDocumentCommand{\mybox}{ O{blue} m }{
%     \begin{tikzpicture}
%     \node[#1](X){\texttt{#2}};
%     \draw[#1](X.north west) rectangle (X.south east)
%              (X.north west)--(X.south east)
%              (X.south west)--(X.north east);
%       \end{tikzpicture}
%     }
\begin{document}
\mybox{A}\quad\mybox[red]{B}\quad\mybox{azerty}

\end{document}



\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(10,10)
  \put(1.75,0.75) {\texttt{A}}  
  \put(0,0) {\textcolor{blue}{\large $\boxtimes$}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}

gives

You can interchange the two rows to put A in the foreground, if you like.

Without pictures or tikzpictures:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace,graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newlength{\myl}
\newcommand\bboxtimes{\textcolor{blue}{$\boxtimes$}\xspace}
\newcommand\cancelbox[1]{\settowidth{\myl}{$\boxtimes$}\ooalign{\makebox[.99\myl]{\raisebox{.09\myl}{\scalebox{.9}{\texttt{#1}}}}\cr\textcolor{blue}{\ensuremath\boxtimes}}\xspace}
\begin{document}
\Large

$\cancelbox{A}\cancelbox{ }
\cancelbox{B}\cancelbox{O}\cancelbox{X}\cancelbox{ }
\cancelbox{T}\cancelbox{I}\cancelbox{M}\cancelbox{E}$

\Huge
\cancelbox{X} x \cancelbox{Y} x \cancelbox{Z}\par
$\boxtimes$ x $\boxtimes$ x $\boxtimes$\par  

\end{document}

